# Set the size of crystal report print image for printing Barcode sticker

Tags: crystal-reports, barcode-scanner

I use crystal report to print barcode in sticker but need to change the height and width. So change height and width in the page set up and make it 3.5 X 2.5 cm. But now it prints a blank page after every sticker and scanner cannot read the barcode anymore.
Here is my code:

```
System.Drawing.Image imageIn = barcode.Encode(iType, product.BarCode, barcode.ForeColor, barcode.BackColor, width, height);
            byte[] value = this.imageToByteArray(imageIn);
            CommonDataSet commonDataSet = new CommonDataSet();
            reportDocument.Load(System.IO.Path.Combine(base.Server.MapPath("~/Reporting/RptFiles/Configuration"), "RptBarcodewise.rpt"));

                CommonDataSet.ProductWiseBarcodePrintDataTableRow productWiseBarcodePrintDataTableRow = commonDataSet.ProductWiseBarcodePrintDataTable.NewProductWiseBarcodePrintDataTableRow();


                productWiseBarcodePrintDataTableRow["ProductNameA"] = product.ProductName;
                productWiseBarcodePrintDataTableRow["BarcodeA"] = value;


                commonDataSet.ProductWiseBarcodePrintDataTable.AddProductWiseBarcodePrintDataTableRow(productWiseBarcodePrintDataTableRow);
```

[image: after decrease size rpt design look like this:]

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is the size of the barcode or just the white page in the end?

Answer (score 0):

You said you change height and width in the page set up and make it 3.5 X 2.5 cm and now it prints a blank page after every sticker and scanner cannot read the barcode anymore.

In some cases, printer set different page size at the time of printing.

So please check the printer page size in printer preference, if the printer page size is not same as barcode page size so you can try to set the printer page size same as your barcode page size (3.5 X 2.5 cm ).

Mabe it will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found that main problem is in crystal report rpt file. I don't know why but the change of page set up makes this problem.For some reason crystal report does not capture the new size. I just create a new crystal report and set its size. then everything works perfect.